# Is it possible to host maven repo on Google Drive or Dropbox?

Tags: maven, google-drive-api, hosting, dropbox

I want to create a repository to host a few libs. At first I thought I could do it through Dropbox using this tutorial: https://code.google.com/p/peter-lavalle/wiki/MavenOnDropBox
However, Dropbox has since changed to a new sharing system without `Public` folder for free users. So I turned to Google Drive, but it doesn't offer a folder link in a similar format to `http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3597441/mvn-repostory/` as shown in the tutorial.

Is it possible to host the maven repository on the Google Drive? Or on Dropbox actually...

Answer (score 0):

If you work alone on a project it is good (This is true if Maven is a version control system, but if not than it is possible to host on dropbox). <del>By the way you can enable public folder in dropbox [dropbox public folder enable](https://www.dropbox.com/enable_public_folder)</del> or `Right click --> Dropbox --> Share link`

Comment: Enabling public folder is not available to free users.
And I don't work alone on the project, that's the main reason why I even want a maven repo...

Comment: But if you make a public folder only you are able to update the repository. Create a shared folder in dropbox and share it (if you do so, all the project participants must install dropbox)